# angularjs | dependency injection advantage over requiring modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

what is the advantage of using dependency injection over requiring modules?

```
/* with dependency injection  */
app.controller('testCtrl', function(dep){
    /* use dep... */
});

/* with require  */
app.controller('testCtrl', function(){
    var dep = require('./dep');
    /* use dep... */
});
```

Comment: With dependency injection unit testing is easier with using mocks

Answer (score 1):

Those are 2 distinct things.

**require** is [AMD's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_module_definition) thing which solves loading of modules so you don't need to include `<script>` tag in order to load `.js` file. For that you can use libraries like [requireJs](http://requirejs.org/)

**angular dependency injection** is angular's thing to load **angular** modules like `$scope`, `$http` etc but those you have in angular and don't need to be loaded with require.

AMD you can use to load another files like another module, service or factory in different file and you want asynchronously load this file when needed you use `define()` or `require()` (see requirejs documentation) to load those files. Once you have files loaded with **require** you need to use **angular's DI** to to get reference to them in order to use them.

Without require you would need to have files from your service included somewhere in `index.html` in `<script>` tag

[this](http://www.startersquad.com/blog/angularjs-requirejs/) is good article about using requirejs in angular.

Hope this will help you clarify stuff.